# How to test app for Vista

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-3.5, testing, windows-vista

I've written an app that connects to websites APIs and does some things there. It is a app written in C#, .NET 3.5 on a XP OS.

Now I have a problem. Some people reported that this application hangs on Vista, and not on the more new version of Windows (what was the name?)

So I do not have Vista and do not have money to buy this system only to test this one, freeware application. Is there any other way to test my app if it is valid for Vista or is there other way to make sure it will be working? I'm in a blind spot here and do not know what to do next.

Update: I use Visual C# Express 2008

Comment: What makes you think there will be bugs? The Framework was designed for this, to run everywhere... especially windows

Comment: My clients reported that program does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [trial version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c2c27337-d4d1-4b9b-926d-86493c7da1aa&displaylang=en) of Vista?

Comment: There are plenty of free VM tools if you don't have a physical PC to install Vista on.  And you could use the RC version of Windows 7 if you're quick - downloads expire 20/08/09: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dd353205.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

On one of my small projects, I've worked out some miscellaneous bugs by connecting to users over Remote Assistance before. At least Visual Studio Shell Edition (free) will let you attach to an existing process, and probably C# Express Edition (free) as well.

(This was an obvious choice for me, since my program is a Visual Studio extension, therefore all of my users have Visual Studio installed.)

Comment: Express does not have connecting to process. Unfortunately I use this version

Comment: @tomaszs: Install Shell Edition side-by-side (it won't affect the Express Edition install). You won't have C# IntelliSense, but you'll have most of the debugging features you're used to. Follow Step 1 [carefully] here: http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:nFringe